# How to draw graph consists of nodes with half edges attached to them?

Tags: graphics

I want to draw a graph with some nodes and some half edges attached to them. Basically something like number a) in the following picture

[image]

Of course I can just draw each node and each half-edge one by one, but is there a way to do it a bit more efficiently if I have many nodes?

Comment: By adding a couple of invisible nodes to a)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1.

Add invisible vertices (as suggested by Henrik in comments):

```
numchildren = {3, 2, 2, 1};

ig = MapIndexed[IndexGraph[#, 10 #2[[1]]] &, 
   CompleteKaryTree[2, #, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"] & /@ numchildren];

vc = Join @@ MapIndexed[
    Thread[VertexList[#] -> (TranslationTransform[{2 #2[[1]], 0}]@
         Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose[GraphEmbedding@#]])] &, ig];

SetProperty[GraphUnion @@ ig, 
  {VertexShapeFunction -> {_?(Mod[#, 10] != 0 &) -> None}, 
  VertexSize -> .75, VertexStyle -> Purple, VertexCoordinates -> vc, 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.01], Green], ImageSize -> Large}]
```

[image]

#### 2.

Alternatively, create a graph with no edges and use a custom `VertexShapeFunction` to add *halfedges*:

```
g0 = Graph[MapThread[Property[#, "children" -> #2] &, {Range[4], numchildren}], {}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> Thread[{Range[4], 0}], VertexStyle -> Purple ];

vSF = {Green, Thickness[.01], 
   Function[x, Line[{#, # + x/3}]] /@ (Through[{Cos, Sin}@#] & /@ 
      MovingAverage[Subdivide[-Pi, 0, PropertyValue[{g0, #2}, "children"]], 2]), 
   PropertyValue[{g0, #2}, VertexStyle], 
   Disk[#, .1]} &; 

 SetProperty[g0, {VertexShapeFunction -> vSF, ImageSize -> Large}]
```

[image]

#### 3.

If you do not need a `Graph` object you can construct a graphics object more directly:

```
n = 4;
numchildren = {3, 2, 2, 1};
vc = Thread[{Range[n], 0}];
lc = Through[{Cos, Sin}@#] & /@ MovingAverage[Subdivide[-Pi, 0, #], 2] & /@ numchildren;

Graphics[{Green, Thickness[.01], 
  MapThread[Function[x, Line[{#, # + x/3}]] /@ #2 &, {vc, lc}], 
  Purple, Disk[#, .1] & /@ vc}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]